# Altium throws unjustly creepage violations

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, clearance, creepage

In my project, I have several rules set for creepage. I get 12 violations on this rule, but always between the polygon and a pad or via.

[image: Rule]

[image: Rule violation]

This is strange because the polygon is drawn by Altium according to this rule.
In fact it is done correctly, because when I measure the distance myself, it shows exactly the distance that I have set in the rules.

[image: Measurement]

In the below image, it seems like the measured distance on which the violation is thrown doesn't exactly touch the copper.
[image: Close up of violation]

Did Anyone ever experience something like this before? I am on the most recent version of Altium, but I also experienced this in AD22.

Comment: That's a pretty small variation, perhaps caused by the way curves are formed from straight lines. I suggest changing the polygon clearance rule to slightly more than 2.5mm, say 2.52 mm (and re-pour, of course).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks for your response, but i dont think this would get rid of the violations, because it would than give a violation on 2.52.

Comment: They are two separate numbers (creepage minimum and polygon clearance) so I don’t think so.

Comment: I would suggest trying @SpehroPefhany idea. Also, can you please give a screen of the properties of any of those pads? I have something in mind, just want to be sure.

Comment: @Ergophobia. Do you mean a screenshot of the via properties? There is not much to it apart from hole size, pad size and soldermask expension.